# Matplotlib image plot - nan values shown as lowest color of colormaps instead of transparent

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, color-mapping

I am using `matplotlib 3.0.3` and want to create an animation of image plots using the `FuncAnimation` module. For plotting speed, I update the image data using `im.set_data` for `imshow` and `im.set_array()` for `plt.pcolormesh` (`set_data` is not available as an attribute). If I update the data partially with NaN values, `imshow` displays them as blank pixels, while `pcolormesh` shows them as the lowest color from the colormap (blue for `viridis`).

Is this intended and if not, why is this the behavior? It seems related to `set_array()`, since `pcolormesh` normally does plot NaN as blank pixels.

Minimal example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig1 = plt.figure()
im1 = plt.pcolormesh(np.random.rand(10,10))
im1.set_array((np.zeros((10,10)) * np.nan).ravel())

fig2 = plt.figure()
im2 = plt.imshow(np.random.rand(10,10))
im2.set_data(np.zeros((10,10)) * np.nan)
```

Answer (score 1):

Matplotlib images do not work well with `nan`s. One should instead use masked arrays. Then both cases are the same (except for the need to flatten the pcolormesh array).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

A = np.random.rand(10,10)
B = np.ma.array(A, mask=np.ones((10,10)))

fig1 = plt.figure()
im1 = plt.pcolormesh(A)
im1.set_array(B.ravel())
plt.colorbar()

fig2 = plt.figure()
im2 = plt.imshow(A)
im2.set_array(B)
plt.colorbar()

plt.show()
```

Comment: Any reasons for why it does not work well with them? I somehow expected some standardized behavior to deal with NaN for all image-related functions.

Comment: I guess mostly historic reasons. When matplotlib was written, numpy `nan` wasn't in a mature state.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest 
I am doing masking by below code 
    import numpy.ma as ma
    z1=ma.masked_invalid(z1)
Masking is working fine But still i am getting nan values plot as lowest values color .
type(z) <class 'numpy.ma.core.MaskedArray'> (280495,)
[0.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 --]